# How to find the User Reputation Level

Tags: apex, customer-community, connect-api, reputation

Is there a way to directly get the user reputation level using ConnectApi. Right now I am querying the user reputation points and then comparing the points with points required to achieve that level using the Reputation Level object.

Currently I am using the following queries to the reputation level,

```
SELECT Id, ReputationPoints  FROM NetworkMember WHERE NetworkId = :networkId AND MemberId = :userId

SELECT Id, Label, Threshold, LevelNumber FROM ReputationLevel WHERE Threshold >= :networkMember.ReputationPoints
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Chatter API (ConnectApi) `ConnectApi.Reputation` class. It has 2 properties:

`reputationLevel` (a reference to a ConnectApi.ReputationLevel), and
`reputationPoints` (a Double that holds the actual number of points the user possesses)